# Do I need a comma before which?

Tags: commas

Introducing the new service, which provides 
support and guidance for those of you 
with caring responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

A sentence needs a subject and a verb. Example:

> Our company is introducing a new service, which provides support and guidance for those of you with caring responsibilities.

Here, the comma is optional. It indicates a pause in the sentence if it were spoken.